# Getting NameError while I already have defined the name. [Classes]

Tags: python-3.x, oop, nameerror

Pythonistas!
First of all, I am a beginner. I just started reading and practicing the Python Crash Course book.
I have reached the OOP chapter where I was given an assignment.

The problem is I am getting a NameError which makes no sense as I have already defined the name.

My code is:

```
class Restaurants():
    """Practicing classes."""
    def __init__(self,name,cuisine):
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine

    def restaurantInfo(self):
        print("The restaurant's name is: "+name.title()+".")
        print("The restaurant's cuisine type is: "+cuisine.title()+".")
    
    def rOpen(self):
        print(name.title()+" is open 24/7.")

restaurant = Restaurants('habibi','fast food')
print(restaurant.name.title()+" is the name of our Restaurant.")
print("We serve "+restaurant.cuisine.title()+".")
restaurant.rOpen()
```

The ERROR occurs at:

```
 line 12, in rOpen
    print(name.title()+" is open 24/7.")
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Use `self.name.title()` and `self.cuisine.title()`

Comment: Thanks, Sociopath.
It worked... but why? I mean, name.title() works fine at my 1st method.
But name.title() raises error at the 2nd method...

I did not understand the reason behind this.

Comment: you need `self` to access the variable outside `__init__` method. Refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) for better understanding